# error in function that counts the number of times an int appears in a list

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, function-pointers

I'm trying to count the number of times a given int occurs in a list, but I'm having a difficult time getting my pointers to work. Can someone spot where is my logic failing? Is it because of how I'm implementing the "follows" "->" in the counting function?

```
//this is in my .h file
typedef struct list_struct LIST;

///// the rest is in my .c file
typedef struct node {
ElemType val;
struct node *next;
} NODE;

struct list_struct {
NODE *front;
NODE *back;
};

//this is my counting function
int lst_count(LIST *l, ElemType x) {
  LIST *current = l;
  int count = 0;

  while (current != NULL) {
      if ((current->front->val) == x) count++;
      current = current->front->next; 
      //in the line above I get the following warning:
      //"incompatible pointer types assigning to 'LIST*' (aka 'struct list_struct*') from 'struct node*'"
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `current = current->front->next` give you an error? Or at least a warning? `current` is a variable of type `LIST*`, and `current->front->next` is a `NODE*`.

Comment: yes. I just added the warning I get

Comment: Well, the warning tells you exactly what you're trying to do that doesn't make sense... so figure out what you actually want to do instead?

Comment: the only issue is that I don't understand how to fix the pointers in this particular situation (i just started learning C) any advise?

Comment: Consider that you are not going to iterate over a set of `LISTS`, but your `current` variable is of type `LIST`. Shouldn't it really be of type `NODE`? As that is what you will iterate over?

Comment: 1) Enable and pay heed to compiler warnings. 2) Do not use all-uppercase for other than macros in C (`FILE` is a very old legacy). This is one of the few well-accepted naming styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the while loop
You are in a list struct, then you do 
current->front->next;
Now you are in a NODE type struct, in the next iteration there is no front in NODE.
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
} NODE;


int lst_count(NODE *l, int x) {
  NODE *current = l;
  NODE *start = current; /* so that we wont loose the start*/
  int count = 0;
  while (current != NULL) {
      if ((current->val) == x)
        count++;
      current = current->next;
  }
  return count;
}

int main()
{
    NODE* p = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NODE* p1 = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NODE* p2 = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NODE* start = p;
    p->val = 5;
    p->next = p1;
    p1->next = p2;
    p2->next=NULL;
    p1->val = 5;
    p2->val = 5;
    printf("%d", lst_count(start, 5));
 }
```

Comment: What's the use of `start` in the function?

Comment: I always put another pointer at the start even tho you could reassign current = l, That is the way I'm used to code...

Comment: I get a warning indicating that the pointer types initializing NODE are incompatible (NODE *current = l;). How can we make them compatible?

Comment: It might be better to use`LIST` as first argument to `lst_count` and assign `current` like `NODE *current = l->front;`.

Comment: I edited my answer with an explanation why your while loop is wrong. Read it.

Comment: Thanks for the help!. I posted the edited function above.

Comment: Yep, you changed the type of your pointer and that fixed your problem, yet the list struct is useless. Follow my code it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I got the function to work thanks to your all advises

```
int lst_count(LIST *l, int x) {
   NODE *current = l->front;
   int count = 0;

   while (current != NULL) {
      if ((current->val) == x) count++;
      current = current->next;
   }
   return count;
}
```